# Populate select list from database in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I need assistance to populate select list in Struts 2.
Have simple registration form in which need to fill select list from database say user name list.

I use below format :

```
<s:select name="username" label="Username" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Search Engines" list="%{#{'value':'front','value1':'front1'}}" theme="simple" onchange="getData(this.value)"/>
```

But how to fill it from database?

Comment: <s:select name="username" label="Username" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Search Engines" list="%{#{'value':'front','value1':'front1'}}" theme="simple" onchange="getData(this.value)"/>

Comment: Please **Edit**  and update your question with above code.

Answer (score 0):

From the database you would get a list of objects that satisfy some criteria.

```java
List<Engine> engines = enginDAO.getEngines();
//getter and setter here
```

Now you have to populate `engines` to the list.

```jsp
<s:select name="username" label="Username" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Search Engines" list="%{engines}" listKey="id" listValue="name" theme="simple" onchange="getData(this.value)"/>
```